# mysql copy to another only new records

Tags: mysql

I have to 2 tables:

lang temp:

```
sku|postid|fi|en|ru (15000 records / included 200 full_products records)
```

full_products:

```
sku|postid|fi|en|ru|xx|zzz|aaaa|bbb (200 records)
```

postid are unical and it cant be same.

I need  to copy only new records from lang temp to full_products. How it's possible do be query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```sql
INSERT INTO full_products (sku,postid,fi,en,ru)
SELECT sku,postid,fi,en,ru
  FROM lang_temp l
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (
   SELECT 1 
     FROM full_products
    WHERE post_id = l.post_id
      AND sku = l.sku
 )
```

Comment: insert and select in some query?

Comment: @user2421781 Exactly. Read [INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: And in phpmtadmin it work only like select, the query dont do any inserting

Comment: It works the same regardless of the tool being used. The problem is in where condition of not exists subquery. In order to do it right can you post sample data for both tables and the result of executing `desc full_products` and `desc lang_temp`

Comment: thank you, now it works, but how i can do chekking - if full_products.postid doesnt math lang_temp , so remove rhe full_products record